# I have created a client script, no error in the script but after deployment, while testing with record, the script is not running

Tags: netsuite, clientscript

I have created a client script, no error in the script but after deployment, while testing with record, the script is not running

[image: Script screenshot]

Comment: Status: Testing means it only runs for the developer not all users. Also post the full deployment information instead of just the deployment list which is a summary. Then add how you are testing etc.

Answer (score 1):

try to disable the un used functions from the final return statement, some of them (validation functions) require to return Boolean values